# Append URL with .load() - loaded content's id or file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading content into a div, and when loaded I want to change the page's URL to reflect the loaded content. I.E. parent page - http://www.example.com/foo - when content is loaded http://www.example.com/foo#content-1

This code is appending it with "#undefined"

```
...
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$("#content").load(href, function() {
            window.location.hash = (this).hash;
        });
```

...
I need to target the loaded content's id or url? I would guess url

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that for browser history:

try this plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Here is the sample: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way? that thing is huuuuge. Can you not just get the loaded content's title attr and append that?

Answer (score 1):

on line 4, you are using (this).hash instead of $(this).hash